# Slow performance on passing large hash by reference to subroutine

Tags: arrays, performance, perl, hash

This code

```
        foreach my $ti (@forward){
           my $new_bs = %blast_values->{ $ti }->{"bitscore"};
           if($new_bs > $fbs){
              $fti = $ti;
              $fbs = $new_bs;
           }
        }
        my $fqstart  = %blast_values->{ $fti }->{"qstart"};
        my $fqend    = %blast_values->{ $fti }->{"qend"};
        my $fsstart  = %blast_values->{ $fti }->{"sstart"};
        my $fsend    = %blast_values->{ $fti }->{"send"};
```

was originally done with a subroutine call:

```
        my ($fti, $fqstart, $fqend, $fsstart, $fsend, $fbs) = best_one(\@forward,\%blast_values);
```

where inside the subroutine it did:

```
        my @forward = @{$_[0]};
        my %blast_values = %{$_[1]};
```

However, the subroutine version ran about 40X slower than did the code shown at the top of this post.  The subroutine version was the same code, just moved into the subroutine and then return the scalar values indicated.  The subroutine would have been called about 30K times if I had let it run to completion, which I never did, because it was going to take about 1800 seconds.  Place debug output line before the "foreach" in the subroutine and there was a noticeable delay between output lines during a run, on the order of 1 second, whereas for the version in the main part of the perl there is no measurable delay (so < 0.1 seconds or so between output lines).

The array was generally very small, with 1 or 2 (99% of the time) entries and rarely up to 12.  The hash, on the other hand, was very, very large.  It has something like 1.5M keys and each key has 6 values accessed by subkeys.  Both are passed by reference, so the size of their contents really should not have mattered.

What might account for this delay?  I do not recall there being this much call overhead on Perl subroutine invocations, and the input parameters are passed by reference, so it isn't like it had to copy the huge hash.  (Although the execution speed suggests maybe it was doing so.)

Perl 5.8.8 on Centos 5.

Comment: Why are making a copy (`my @forward = @{$_[0]}; my %blast_values = %{$_[1]};`)? Use `my ($forward, $blast_values) = @_;`

Comment: `my ($forward, $blast_values) = @_;` and later on use $forward->[x], and $blast_values->{y}.

Answer (score 6):

It's slow because when you do this

```
my @forward = @{$_[0]};
my %blast_values = %{$_[1]};
```

You are dereferencing the references you passed in and *copying* the referenced structures into new variables. If `%blast_values` is very big, that's a lot of work.

Instead, just use the references without copying. (That's what they're for.)

```
my $forward = shift;
my $blast_values = shift;

my $fqstart  = $blast_values->{ $fti }->{"qstart"};
# etc
```

Also, I assume you're aware that `%blast_values->{ $fti }->{"qstart"}` doesn't make sense. The fact that it works at all is due to a bug in Perl. Using such a construct has issued a warning ("Using a hash as a reference is deprecated") for years. You should have been using `$blast_values{ $fti }->{"qstart"}`.

Comment: So that should have been?    my @forward = $_[0];
    my %blast_values = $_[1];

Comment: This syntax is encountered often in examples for passing a hash by reference:  my $params = shift; my %paramhash = %$params;  Does that also dereference (copy) the hash?  Never mind, further down in the thread where I saw that I now see it says that method does indeed copy.

Comment: `my ($forward, $blast_values) = @_;` is faster than shifting off the values one at a time, particularly on 5.20 and later.